# Remove item from a list on second select

Tags: jquery, list, removeclass

I would like to remove an item from drop down list not on first time, but after selecting a second item, in the bellow example if I select option1 will remove option1, but I need to select option1 (nothing will be removed), while selecting option4 (now option1 will be removed):

```
<select name="selectBox" class="sel" id="selectBox">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>    
</select>
```

And this is the code:

```
$(".sel").change(function () {
  var getVal = $(this).val();
  $("#selectBox option[value="+getVal+"]").remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aburayane/0bj7vm9k/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove previously selected option then do something like this

```js
var getVal;
$(".sel").change(function() {
  // checking previous value is defined or not
  if (getVal)
  // if defined removing the element
    $("#selectBox option[value=" + getVal + "]").remove();
  // updating selected option value to variable
  getVal = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" class="sel" id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

Or something more simple using **[`:selected`](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)** selector

```js
var getVal;
$(".sel").change(function() {
  // removing previous selected option
  $(getVal).remove();
  // updating selected option object to variable
  getVal = $(':selected', this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="selectBox" class="sel" id="selectBox">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
  <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
```

**Update:** Initially trigger change event using **[`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/)** to get default value if you needed.

```
$(".sel").change(function() {
   //.............
}).change();
//--^--
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var theValue;
$('.sel').focus(function () {
    theValue = $(this).attr('value');
});

$(".sel").change(function () {
    $('.sel option[value=' + theValue + ']').remove();
    theValue = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bwsnpr7r/3/)

Comment: this code is deleting the same selected item on the same time while selecting, I think Pranav C Balan answer is the correct one

Comment: i must have misunderstood the question i updated the answer hope it fits the requirements now @OumAlaa

Comment: The select button also disappears